# Creating a vignette with SVG filters?

Tags: svg, filter, svg.js

I would like to create vignette on an image using SVG filters. What is the best way to approach this? I already tried creating a `feFlood` with a gradient as `flood-color` but that doesn't work. Right now I am using a png generated in illustrator but I would like to keep it all in svg.

To illustrate what I am aiming for, this is the original:

[image: without vignette]

And this is what is should be:

[image: with vignette]

UPDATE:

I am using [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/) with the [svg.filter.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.filter.js) plugin to generate the code dynamically. This is what I tried:

```
// create svg canvas
var draw = SVG('canvas').size(400,400)

// define gradient
var gradient = draw.gradient('radial', function(stop) {
    stop.at({ offset: 0, opacity: 0 })
    stop.at({ offset: 1 })
})
gradient.radius('80%')

// create image
var image = draw.image('http://distilleryimage11.ak.instagram.com/89ac2e90d9b111e297bf22000a1f9263_7.jpg').size(400,400)

// add filter
image.filter(function(add) {
    add.blend(add.source, add.flood(gradient), 'multiply')
})
```

This is the generated code:

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"     style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;left:0px;top:0px;">
    <image id="SvgjsImage1005" xlink:href="http://distilleryimage11.ak.instagram.com/89ac2e90d9b111e297bf22000a1f9263_7.jpg" width="400" height="400" filter="url(    #SvgjsFilter1006)"></image>
    <defs id="SvgjsDefs1001">
        <radialGradient id="SvgjsRadialGradient1002" r="80%">
            <stop id="SvgjsStop1003" stop-opacity="0" offset="0"></stop>
            <stop id="SvgjsStop1004" offset="1"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <filter id="SvgjsFilter1006">
            <feFlood id="SvgjsFeFlood1007" in="SourceGraphic" result="SvgjsFeFlood1007Out" flood-color="url(#SvgjsRadialGradient1002)"></feFlood>
            <feBlend id="SvgjsFeBlend1008" in="SourceGraphic" result="SvgjsFeBlend1008Out" in2="SvgjsFeFlood1007Out" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

The result is a completely black image. It seems that the feFlood element does not accept gradients as fill because it works with a color.

Here is a fiddle with the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/wout/VmUu6/

Comment: Can you post the specific code you've tried?

Comment: Is using filters absolutely required?  Because you could achieve this affect with a masked rectangle over the top of your image.

Comment: Yes, in this case it needs to be part of the filter. The image should be the only element; besides the defs of course, where anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me without spotlighting, I user a radial gradient with multiple stop points you can adjust the color, stop points and opacity level to get the effect you want. play with the r(radius to widen/shorten the effect and the fx,fy to position.  Gradients tend to be more efficient then using some of the filters that require heavy maths processing

```
<radialGradient id="grad"
                fx="50%" fy="50%" r="55%"
                spreadMethod="pad">
    <stop offset="30%"   stop-color="#222222" stop-opacity="0"/>
    <stop offset="40%"   stop-color="#222222" stop-opacity="0.2"/>
    <stop offset="50%"   stop-color="#222222" stop-opacity="0.4"/>
    <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#222222" stop-opacity="0.6" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#222222" stop-opacity="1" />
</radialGradient>
```

Apply to the rectangle positioned above an image

```
  <image id="background" x="0" y="0" width="800px" height="530px"  preserveAspectRatio="true"
     xlink:href="http://i1-qa.adis.ws/i/Client_23/ss_collection_reddress?w=800"/>
<rect filter="url(#blur)" style="fill:url(#grad)" x="0" y="0" width="800px" height="530px"/>
```

[vignette example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clDuH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have some vignetteing and selecting compositing methods in my [slide share preso on filters.](http://www.slideshare.net/mullany1/svg-filters-html5-devconf-apr-2013) Page 50 onwards for techniques. Here is the most relevant piece of filter code. It's not a real vignette - that requires a much longer filter and selective image combination, but it's easier to understand.

```
 <filter>
        <feFlood id="flood-5" result="blackfield-6" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="blackfield-6" flood-color="#000000" flood-opacity="1"/>
        <feSpecularLighting id="specular-5" result="Spotlight-6" lighting-color="#FFFFFF" surfaceScale="1" specularConstant="1" specularExponent="120">
            <fePointLight id="pointlight-5" x="100" y="100" z="854"/>
        </feSpecularLighting>
        <feBlend id="svg-7" result="A-6" in="blackfield-6" in2="Spotlight-6" mode="lighten"/>
        <feBlend id="blend-5" result="B-6" in="A-6" in2="SourceGraphic" mode="multiply"/>
    </filter>
```